# Mysql sum with sort of concate

Tags: mysql

Is there a possibility for a sort of concatting before the Sum function in a query? I've the following query:

```
SELECT 
  orders.id AS orderId,
  orders.delivery_from,
  orders.delivery_to,
  orders_products.product_id,
  orders_products.color_id,
  orders_products.size_id,
  SUM(orders_products.quantity) AS quantity,
  customers.id AS customerId,
  customers.name AS customerName,
  products.name 
FROM
  orders 
  INNER JOIN orders_products 
    ON orders_products.order_id = orders.id 
  INNER JOIN customers 
    ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
  INNER JOIN products 
    ON orders_products.product_id = products.id 
  LEFT JOIN orders_product_data 
    ON orders_product_data.order_id = orders.id 
    AND orders_product_data.product_id = orders_product.product_id 
    AND orders_product_data.color_id = orders_product.color_id 
WHERE orders.status = '0' 
  AND (
    orders.delivery_from <= '2014-05-05' 
    AND orders.delivery_to >= '2014-05-05'
  ) 
  AND (
    (orders_products_data.delivery_from <= '2014-05-05' || orders_products_data.delivery_to = 0) 
    AND (orders_products_data.delivery_from >= '2014-05-05' || orders_products_data.delivery_to = 0)
  ) 
GROUP BY customer_id,
  product_id,
  color_id,
  size_id
```

I would like the quantity of products ordered for each customer. Of course, I can calculate this with an inner join, but is there a beter way?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you are trying to achieve sorting or something else ?

Comment: I would like a sum for each customer_id with the total quantity of products in orders_products. But the difficult part is the where statement in the main query, this where statement is also applied for the total quantity of products for each customer (order status and delivery date)

Comment: Is there someone with an idee?

Comment: Its better if you can provide the sample data set for the query and also add your expected result that you need ,if so then it will helpful to understand your complete problem try this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ online database tool add your table definitions with some sample data and in your question add desired result set

Comment: I've made a simplified SQL fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c0b7/2
A summery of my question: I would like an extra field in the where statement for selecting all orders for each customer which have more than 400 products (so, in the SQL Fiddle case, just customer 1).

Comment: Just posted the answer have a look at and also [**see demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c0b7/12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from comments you can do so an additional join using subselect and this will be inner join and will get only customers that have products morethan 400

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONVERT(o.id, CHAR(11))) orders, 
  o.delivery_from,
  o.delivery_to,
  o.customer_id,
  op.product_id, 
  op.color_id,
  op.size_id,
  sum(op.quantity) as quantity
FROM orders o
  INNER JOIN orders_products op  ON op.order_id=o.id
  LEFT JOIN orders_products_data opd ON opd.order_id=o.id 
AND opd.product_id=op.product_id
AND opd.color_id=op.color_id
JOIN (SELECT customer_id FROM orders o
      JOIN orders_products op ON(op.order_id=o.id)
     GROUP BY customer_id
      HAVING SUM(op.quantity) >400
     ) t
ON(o.customer_id = t.customer_id)
WHERE
  o.status='0' AND
  (o.delivery_from <= '2014-05-05' 
   AND o.delivery_to >='2014-05-05') 
   AND
  ((opd.delivery_from<='2014-05-05' 
    || opd.delivery_to=0) 
     AND (opd.delivery_from>='2014-05-05' ||
          opd.delivery_to=0))
GROUP BY o.customer_id ,
op.product_id, 
op.color_id, 
op.size_id
```

For above query you should index your columns that are used in `ON()` clause and also index your date columns that are involved in your where filter

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9c0b7/12)

Comment: I solution is an inner join, but unfortunately it isn't that easy since the where statement select orders by:
1. Status (only 0)
2. Delivery date of order (from / to)
3. Delivery date of each unique order_id - product_id - color_id combination in orders_products_data (from /to).
Look for example at the following SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25f29/1 . I've added an extra order (7) for customer 2 and status (1). So, this order should not count for the total customer quantity.

Of course we can make an inner join with exactly the same where statement, but isn't there a better way?

Comment: I guess there is no easy way to achieve this type of conditions because your main query group records by `.customer_id,op.product_id,op.color_id,op.size_id` but the quantity condition for each customer you need > 400 so i guess you need another query with only group by customer and then join with your main query

Comment: Oké, that was already what i thought. But what about the speed of the query? I think a second join for getting the quantity each customer will really slow it down. I've already indexed the table really well.

Comment: @Stefan run this query on your production data with `SQL_NO_CACHE` and also get the explain plan of the query this will give us the right idea for the performance of query

Comment: The performance didn't really drop (with a quantity of more than 0, thus all the results): original query: about 0.14s for 1.302 results, new query about 0.16 for the same number of results.
So, I will use the join for getting the quantity for each customer. If you ever find a better one, keep me in mind ;-) Of course I will post it when I find it..

Comment: @Stefan sure i will let you know